# Python 3.4 + installed, python program that requires it still not running?

Tags: python

I am trying to run a python program, I installed python, 3.5 but it still says.

```
requires Python 3.4 or newer.
```

When ever I try and start it, am I doing something wrong? I installed python via the package downloaded from the python website

Comment: How are you starting it? and what is your PATH?

Comment: python -m  its a bunch of py files in a directory.

Comment: any your PATH is - what does `type -p python` show as the executable that python is?

Comment: /usr/bin/python

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your $PATH environment variable finds Apple's python 2.7 before the python.org one in /usr/local/bin

One way is to run the script as `/usr/local/bin/python`

Or run as `python3`

Another is to alter your path so /usr/local/bin is before /usr/bin . This has bee described in many questions

Comment: You can also do `python3 **program**` instead of just `python **program**` which will use the other version.